# What might prevent a NodeJS App Service on Azure from sending responses to an SSE event stream?

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, server-sent-events, iisnode

We've developed a NodeJS/Express web app locally and added some new features that utilize Server Sent Events (SSE).  When testing locally, clients are able to connect to the server, register, and receive updates from the server via SSE.  However, when we deploy the web app to Azure, the features that require SSE are non-functional.  The clients are able to initiate the connection, but and the server sees the connection, but then the connection is immediately closed and the client receives a message with status 500 / internal server error.  We are first trying to determine the exact point of failure, and then how to correct, as we assume something in either IIS or IISnode is eating the response.

We've been all over the internets, but we've nothing we've implemented has seemed to help.  We've tried just about every combination of configurations we can find.  I've excerpted the relevant bits of our web.config below, which we understand should pass control of websocket & related transports to the underlying nodejs server rather than having iis or iisnode handle it?  We've also turned on web sockets and always on in the configuration, but to no avail.

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
       <handlers>
           <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" responseBufferLimit="0" />
.
.
.
<iisnode watchedFiles="*.js;node_modules\*;routes\*.js;views\*.jade" flushResponse="true" />
```

We would expect that the Azure deployment should work it does locally -- that clients connected to the server would receive all broadcasts via SSE, but instead they just receive the 500 / internal server error messages.

Comment: What features did utilize SSE? Could you post your App dependencies? I doubt some features in your app conflict with Azure WebApp limits possibly.

Answer (score 0):

@tbr123psu the question is missing few details without which it is difficult to point in the right direction. For example I see that you are using the Windows offering to host your Node app, and you also indicated that the status code was 500. It is important to know what is the substatus as it provides pointers on where the problem might be. See this [IISNODE http status and Substatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-nodejs-best-practices-and-troubleshoot-guide#iisnode-http-status-and-substatus).

> NOTE: On Windows App Service Plan, IIS is used as the underlying web server. For Node.JS application IIS uses the **IISNode** to process requests.

Additionally , I would recommend to turn on **Application Logging** for your Azure Web App. This option is available in the portal under **Diagnostic Logs**. Refer this: [Azure Web App: How to enable diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enablediag)

Refer this blogpost on how to **debug Node.JS apps hosted on Azure App Service**: https://azureossd.github.io/2015/08/19/debug-node-js-web-apps-on-azure/

Once you have the logging enabled, the data emitted will point you in the direction of what is causing the failure.